# Xcode4 iPhone/iPad- How can I build a apps with Contact like contact in iphone?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2, xcode4.3

How can i build a apps like contact in iPhone by using AddressBook.h and AddressBookUI.h?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start by reading through the documentation. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html

You can also perform searches for "ios address book example" to find numerous tutorials.